# call function in ajax success callback

Tags: ajax, angular

Is it possible to call a function in success callback of ajax request?

For example I have something like that :

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient,private serviceComposition: CompositionService) { }

[...]

save() {

    var isValid = this.isValidCompo();

    if (true) {
        var toSend = JSON.stringify(this.setupComposition);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/setup/composition/addSetupComposition",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: 'setupComposition=' + toSend,
            success:function(response){
                //console.log("Success Save Composition");

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
                console.log("Error Save Compo");
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            this.serviceComposition.changeValue(isValid);
        })
    } 
}
```

I want to call a function of my service (named  : changeValue() )  if my ajax request is a success.

But I have this error message : `core.js:12632 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeValue' of undefined`

Do you know if it's possible to resolve that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1):

I am suspecting this binding is going wrong in call backs,
 prefer using arrow function because of "this" operator binding.

```
 if (true) {
    var toSend = JSON.stringify(this.setupComposition);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/setup/composition/addSetupComposition",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'setupComposition=' + toSend,
        success:function(response){
            //console.log("Success Save Composition");

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
            console.log("Error Save Compo");
        }
    }).done((data) => {
        this.serviceComposition.changeValue(isValid);
    })
}
```

if not u can store this reference in a variable and call it

```
 var self = this;
 if (true) {
    var toSend = JSON.stringify(this.setupComposition);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/setup/composition/addSetupComposition",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'setupComposition=' + toSend,
        success:function(response){
            //console.log("Success Save Composition");

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
            console.log("Error Save Compo");
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        self.serviceComposition.changeValue(isValid);
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot both method work well ! Do you know if it's possible to call get ajax function in the success of my POST request ? to replace isValid by a result of a get request

Answer (score 0):

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to access `this` of your parent scope. In your example, `this` is referring to your jQuery XHR object.

So:

```
// [parent scope]

$.ajax({
  ...
}).done((data) => {
  // [child scope]
  // `this` now refers to [parent scope], so the following is valid
  this.serviceComposition.changeValue(isValid);
});
```

Another common practice prior to arrow functions (ES6) would've been assigning a `const self = this;` variable in the `[parent scope]` area to be accessed in the child method. Either method works the same.

Also [check out the MDN docs on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). It's a confusing topic for many.